# Inserting data into a Access Database

Tags: java, database, prepared-statement

I am having trouble with a exercise I am working on with Java using a Access Database, wondering if anyone could shed some light on this

In my main class I make a call like this

```
Product p = new Product("test", "Test Product", 49.50);
insertProduct(p);
```

This calls the insertProduct(p); method. What I am trying to do is insert some test data into the database, here is my code for that.

```
public static void insertProduct(Product p)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Insert test: ");

        String insertProduct = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductCode, Description, Price) VALUES ('andr', 'Beginning Android', '38.99')";
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertProduct);
        ps.setString(1, p.getCode());
        ps.setString(2, p.getDescription());
        ps.setDouble(3, p.getPrice());
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        rs.next();
        String productCode = rs.getString(1);
        String description = rs.getString(2);
        double price = rs.getDouble(3);

        p = new Product(productCode, description, price);


        printProduct(p);
        System.out.println();

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I run this I get a

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

and can't figure out what is going on, I know that when I run the debugger and step through the method, it crashes at the beginning of this statements

```
ps.setString(1, p.getCode());
ps.setString(2, p.getDescription());
ps.setDouble(3, p.getPrice());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

here is the results of the stack trace

```
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.clearParameter(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1023)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setChar(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:3057)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setString(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:766)
at DBTesterApp.insertProduct(DBTesterApp.java:165)
at DBTesterApp.main(DBTesterApp.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of your exception? Is `p` or `ps` null?

Comment: Another possibility is that p.getCode() or p.getDescription() or p.getPrice() return null. (these values are also not used in the SQL)

Comment: "This is the results of the stack trace" : I can't see it

Comment: @pamphlet it is just null I can't tell, how do I check that?

Comment: @PsyChotic, try following up on @NickJ's suggestion. Make sure `p.getCode()` and `p.getDescription()` aren't returning null.

Comment: Also, what happens if you don't use those three statements? Given that your statement is constructed with data in side it, the issue may be that your SQL is parameterized.

Comment: Hmm I am totally lost on this. When calling this method I send in new Product object p, that has the properties initialized to dummy values should I reintialize the object properties once in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in the stack trace:

```
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setString(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:766)
```

indicates that it fell over during your call to PreparedStatement.setString(), which indicates that either p.getCode() or p.getDescription() returns null.

There is therefore a problem in your Product class. Are you setting those fields correctly in the constructor?

Once you've fixed that, you may be disappointed to find that all your rows you insert have exactly the same data.

Look at you SQL to find out why:

```
String insertProduct = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductCode, Description, Price) VALUES ('andr', 'Beginning Android', '38.99')";
```

This should be:

```
String insertProduct = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductCode, Description, Price) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out. The database that I was using was read only, I had to configure write access to the database, when I did this it worked fine.